# How to convert GeneXus web forms from the HTML editor to the abstract editor in many objects?

Tags: sdk, genexus

I have a GeneXus KB that has webpanels and transactions that use the old editor for web forms.
Is there a way to bulk convert to the new abstract editor?
Can I make an extension to do it using the Genexus SDK ?

Can I make this change with an extension, using the GeneXus SDK?

Or can I do it with the IDE in bulk?

[image: Convert to Abstract Editor]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no option to convert in bulk.

You can make an extension that does it

1. Within a web form there are multiple forms that can be the new Layout or the old Html layout, so first, you have to enumerate those

   using Artech.Genexus.Common.Parts;

   var webForm = webPanel.WebForm;
   foreach (MultiFormSerializer.Form form in MultiFormSerializer.GetForms(webForm.Document))
2. To know which ones need conversion, you can check the handle

   using Artech.Genexus.Common.Parts.WebForm;

   if (form.Handler == MultiForm.Html)
3. Then create the new form

   XmlElement elem = MultiForm.Layout.CreateForm(GetUniqueControlName)

   private string GetUniqueControlName(string baseControlName, bool startWithIndex) { return baseControlName; } // if you only have 1 form, you can just return that, else it must return a unique control name
4. Make the conversion

   MultiForm.Layout.ConvertFrom(kbObj, elem, form.Handler, form.RootElement)
5. Finally, assuming there is just one layout, save it

   var newForm = new MultiFormSerializer.Form(1, MultiForm.Layout, elem)

   webForm.Document = MultiFormSerializer.SaveForms(1, new List {
   newForm })

   webPanel.Save()

I haven't tested this code, but those are the steps that you have to do.
If you have a problem, let me know.